# Garbage char when reading from file

Tags: c, char

I have a file that stores the available seats in a theater. When I read the first few characters, they are garbage. Why is that?

```
bool readSeat(char** a) {
    FILE* file = fopen(SEAT, "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    char ch;
    while (fscanf(file, "%c", &ch) == 1)
    {
        //save ch into **a above
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my file:

```
00000000000001000000000000111
01011111000000000000001111000
00000000000000000000000000000
00000000001111100000000000111
00011111000000000000001111000
00000000000000000000000000000
00000000000001001111000000111
11100011000000000000001111000
00101101111111111100000000000
00000000000001000000000000111
11111111000000000000001111000
00000000000000000000000000000
00000111111111000000000000111
11111111000000000000001111000
10000000001111000000000000000
```

Output:

```
■0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0//...
```

Update:
While debugging, I noticed the 2 first characters are 'ÿ'(-1) and 'þ'(-2).

Comment: It's a 2D array

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way, is there a DOS/UNIX file discrepancy?

Comment: [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) maybe?

Comment: @jiveturkey I'm not native so I don't quite understand your question. If my answer is not relevant then I apologize in advance. I use Windows, so DOS text file?

Comment: Regarding your update: 0xFFFE (-1 -2) is UTF-16 BOM for little endian. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: why a complicated *fscanf* while *fgetc* it so simple ? Out of that, and if not the BOM, it is possible the problem is in the hidden code where you save the read char. Show that hidden code

Comment: View the file with a binary read viewer . . . I bet the characters are in the file.